# How to create array from string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like below

```
  Ontario;Northwest Territories;Nunavut;Prince Edward Island
```

from this string I need to create an array of string like

```
 territoty:Array<string> = [Ontario,Northwest Territories,Nunavut,Prince 
 Edward Island]
```

in javascript.

How can I create the array from the string?

Comment: `territory = str.split(';')`, and you probably mean typescript.

Comment: Please do a reasonable amount of research before posting a question. A Google search using the title of your question turns up the split method in the very first hit. Don't use Stack Overflow as a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Use split:

```
var arrayString = 'Ontario;Northwest Territories;Nunavut;Prince Edward Island';
var territories = arrayString.split(';');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let territories = 'Ontario;Northwest Territories;Nunavut;Prince Edward Island'.split(';');
```

The `split` method is available on strings. It takes a string<sup>1</sup> as an argument and this argument is the delimiter upon which the original string is split. The method then returns an array of strings.

So for your string, `;` is the delimiter. It [delimits](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/delimit) the territory names. The array of territory names is what is returned.

---

1. you can also pass in a regular expression, but that is not relevant for this problem.

Comment: It would be nice if you add some explanation along with your code.

Comment: @L.F. OK. updated.

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = 'Ontario; Northwest Territories; Nunavut; Prince Edward Island'
    var array = str.split(";"); 
    document.write(array);
```